# Widget issue: BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget, android-broadcast

My app widget stops working after upgrading to targetSDk to 28.

- It is flawlessly working on old targetsdk devices.

I am getting the following error:

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=ch.corten.aha.worldclock.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to ch.corten.aha.worldclock/.WorldClockWidgetProvider
W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=ch.corten.aha.worldclock.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to ch.corten.aha.worldclock/.WeatherWidgetProvider
```

**androidmanifest.xml** file contents are given below-

```
       <!-- clock widget -->
    <receiver
        android:name=".WorldClockWidgetProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/clock_widget_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ch.corten.aha.worldclock.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ch.corten.aha.worldclock.CLOCK_TICK" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/world_clock_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
<receiver
        android:name=".WeatherWidgetProvider"
        android:enabled="@bool/enable_weather_widget"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/weather_widget_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ch.corten.aha.worldclock.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ch.corten.aha.worldclock.CLOCK_TICK" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/weather_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

And my reviever class code(

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())
            || CLOCK_TICK_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (pm.isScreenOn()) {
            onClockTick(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Where clock widget provider is extending AppWidgetProvider.

**world clock activity**

```
  private static void sendWidgetRefresh(Context context) {
        // send update broadcast to widget
        Intent broadcast = new Intent(ClockWidgetProvider.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED_ACTION);
        context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
```

project [link](https://github.com/dasbiswajit/worldclockwidget/blob/d401a5c363007251ee9450826fb2372e00c09093/worldclockwidget/src/main/java/ch/corten/aha/worldclock/UpdateWeatherService.java) for reference. Followed previous posts but did not worked.

[Oreo - Widget services and broadcast receiver: Not allowed to start service Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984211/oreo-widget-services-and-broadcast-receiver-not-allowed-to-start-service-inte)

Comment: Any pointer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is in implicit broadcast that you're making in **sendWidgetRefresh**.
You can break through the ban by defining a component name in your intent.

```
private static void sendWidgetRefresh(Context context) {
    // send update broadcast to widget
    Intent broadcast = new Intent(ClockWidgetProvider.WIDGET_DATA_CHANGED_ACTION);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WorldClockWidgetProvider.class);
    broadcast.setComponent(componentName);
    context.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!
Change your implicit intent to explicit intent, because starting Oreo implicit intents don't run in background!
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html